# What is the solution of B for equation derivative of B^TΛΒ wrt B = 0?

Tags: matrix-calculus

So we are at a state where $\partial B^TΛΒ / \partial B  = 0$

Trying to solve it using formula (53) of `Matrix Cookbook`.

We derive that B = 0
Is this correct ??

To give you some context we are trying to solve Expectation-Maximization for Gaussian Mixture Models from scratch. That's why Λ = Σ^-1 and B = x - μ

Comment: please use math formatting. more information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Sycorax I already did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $\Lambda$ is invertible, you are correct. The derivative (represented as a column vector) is $2\Lambda B$ (edit: as long as $\Lambda$ is symmetric), and if $\Lambda$ is invertible, then $2\Lambda B=0$ implies $B=0$.

Comment: Thank you for verifying. I guess the issue is somewhere else in my code

Comment: That's true if $\Lambda$ is symmetric, but not true in general. $\frac{\partial \mathbf{b}' \Lambda \mathbf{b}}{\partial \mathbf{b}} = \left( \Lambda + \Lambda' \right) \mathbf{b}$.